# How to convert string date in Kotlin

Tags: date, kotlin

I have a date of string type `"2020-08-10"`. How to convert my string date to this format `Monday 08 2020` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
var parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-08-10", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
println("2020-08-10 : "+parsedDate.dayOfWeek.toString()+" "+parsedDate.monthValue+" "+parsedDate.year)
```

Output:

```
2020-08-10 : MONDAY 8 2020
```

For API 26 Below:

```
val parser =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MM yyyy")
val formattedDate = formatter.format(parser.parse("2020-08-10"))
println("2020-08-10 : "+formattedDate)
```

Output:

```
2020-08-10 : MONDAY 8 2020
```

Comment: This requires API 26. What about APIs below 26?

Answer (score 2):

The `EEEE` prints the name of day

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val str = "2020-08-10"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")    
val dateTime = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter)
    
println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE MM yyyy ")))
```

Output

```
 Monday 08 2020
```

It's an alternative solution to your question.

Comment: @Artem If you found my solution helpful then vote it as heplful.